# "JSON data document " output wrapped with HTML

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm following this tutorial http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/android-app-with-drupal-7-services-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile
It describes how to create views with JSON output. But on step 19 I get my JSON wrapped with HTML so that is showed as an article. By the way it is works just fine with "XML data document " I got my XML without any unexpected HTML wrapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a checkbox in view settings called "Views API mode" it should be uncheked:
[image]

Comment: I didn't found this menu in my drupal. Can you give me more infos how can i find the page from your screenshot?

Comment: @Happo In admin panel: **structure** -> **views** then look for your view and press edit, then found **FORMAT** section and click  **Settings** Scroll down a bit and you'll find **Views API mode** checkdox after **Content-Type** section

Comment: This will not work, if you have multiple views to show in one proceess (e.g. as batch)